# Angular 2 -- Bootstrap carousel not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am trying to build a carousel. I have followed the Bootstrap example as precisely as I can but I am not getting a carousel. The images are appearing horizontally as opposed to being displayed in a slide. Is there a problem with this code?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="product-image" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#product-image" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#product-image" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div [ngClass]="{active: first}">
                    <img src="..\assets\img\{{product.images.productImage[0]}}">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>{{product.make}}</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div [ngClass]="{active: first}">
                    <img src="..\assets\img\{{product.images.productImage[1]}}">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>{{product.make}}</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#product-image" 
                role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#product-image" 
                role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included bootstrap.min.js and jquery in your application?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my case. It was bootstrap version issue. Tried using different version and one of them had carousel displayed correctly. Not mentioning the versions because I was building carousel using different method, but posting answer because problem was same - slides being displayed as a stack and no errors in console or anywhere.